# dual installation of windows and ubuntu stuck on GNU GRUB

Tags: 16.04, boot, bios

i have a windows hp laptop that i installed ubuntu 16.04 on (side by side with the windows OS).

it worked fine for a while, but  now its stuck in the first screen that asks you which OS to load. it says GNU GRUB version 2.02 on the top.

all other questions i saw about this have a terminal solution, but I cant get to the terminal and pretty much the whole computer is stuck.

Note: it sounds like the processor  is working on something (can hear the fan), but still no response.

any ideas?[image]

Comment: I would hit <e> to edit the entry, remove the 'quiet splash' (on linux kernel line) so plymouth isn't visible & all messages are shown (which may provide a clue), and likely add a ' 1 ' too  so it starts at runlevel 1 (doesn't attempt to load gui).  What you get though is unclear?  Does it count down from 10s in photo and then screen blank, then ???   or does the screen not count down or ever leave the 'grub' screen?

Comment: Are you saying the grub screen as pictured is frozen and even arrow keys don't work?

Comment: Nothing have worked on that screen, count down from  10  did not cont down, and the computer was working HARD. I evenally managed to start it up by killing all power and running again, but this is not a very good solution. should I be    worry of some virus or something?